# Swift: Missing Strange Parameter

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I made a method in my ViewController class called `refresh`.

I call `refresh` from a View Controller of a view that is presented modally over the default view. However, although my method `refresh` takes in no parameters, XCode is telling me `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call` during my call to the method. I call the method like this: `ViewController.refresh()`

If I press `esc` in between the parantheses of the method call, Xcode tells me to put in `ViewController`. However, if I run that, Xcode gives me two errors:

```
Expression resolves to an unused function
Editor placeholder in source file
```

Is this because I my secondary view controller is in a folder that doesn't contain my primary view controller?

Update: Here is my refresh method:

```
self.getSortedSectionList()
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

self.getSortedSectionList() is this:

```
//First, clear all events from sectionList
    sectionList = [Int: [Event]]()
    //loop through the eventList array and seperate the different event starting times
    for index in 0..<ViewController.eventList.count {
        let event = ViewController.eventList[index]
        if var arr = sectionList[event.startTime!] {
            //if there is at least one value there, add onto the array
            arr.append(event)
            sectionList[event.startTime!] = arr
        } else {
            //otherwise it is nil, so create the array
            let arr: [Event] = [event]
            sectionList[event.startTime!] = arr
        }
    }
    sortedKeys = Array(sectionList.keys).sort(<)
```

Comment: Can you show how you defined your `refresh` method?

Comment: I added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `ViewController` is a class name of your controller and `refresh` is not a static method. You should call `refresh()` using the object of your controller, not a class.